# Clockwise and counterclockwise spiral matrix traversal

Tags: java, interview-questions, matrix

An interviewer asked me to write clean Java code for clockwise and counterclockwise spiral matrix traversal.

e.g. `{{1,2,3}, {7,8,9}}` becomes `{1,2,3,9,8,7}` and `{1,7,8,9,3,2}`

I've tried many methods and wrote down the below code while keeping in mind that it should be as clean as possible. But I am not sure it is the right answer. Please evaluate it.

Note: I've removed comments and test cases to reduce text size.

```
public abstract class MatrixTraverse {
    private TraverseDirection traverseDirection;
    private int matrixCount;
    private int row;
    private int upLimit;
    private int col;
    private int downLimit;
    private int leftLimit;
    private int rightLimit;
    public abstract void traverseUp();
    public abstract void traverseLeft();
    public abstract void traverseDown();
    public abstract void traverseRight();
    public MatrixTraverse(final TraverseDirection traverseDirection) {
        this.traverseDirection = traverseDirection;
    }
    public void init(int[][] matrix) {
        final int rowSize = matrix.length;
        final int colSize = matrix[0].length;
        upLimit = 0;
        downLimit = matrix.length - 1;
        leftLimit = 0;
        rightLimit = matrix[0].length - 1;
        matrixCount = rowSize * colSize;
        row = 0;
        col = 0;
    }
    public int[] traverseMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        init(matrix);
        final int[] retTraveserdMatrix = new int[matrixCount];
        for (int index = 0; index < matrixCount; index++) {
            retTraveserdMatrix[index] = matrix[row][col];
            switch (traverseDirection) {
                case RIGHT :
                    traverseRight();
                    break;
                case DOWN :
                    traverseDown();
                    break;
                case LEFT :
                    traverseLeft();
                    break;
                case UP :
                    traverseUp();
                    break;
                default :
                    break;
            }
        }
        return retTraveserdMatrix;
    }
    protected void moveDown() {
        traverseDirection = TraverseDirection.DOWN;
    }
    public void moveRight() {
        traverseDirection = TraverseDirection.RIGHT;
    }
    protected void moveLeft() {
        traverseDirection = TraverseDirection.LEFT;
    }
    protected void moveUp() {
        traverseDirection = TraverseDirection.UP;
    }
    public void decrementRow() {
        --row;
    }
    public boolean isUpLimitExceed() {
        return (row < upLimit);
    }
    public void incrementLeftLimit() {
        ++leftLimit;
    }
    public void incrementCol() {
        ++col;

    }
    public void incrementRow() {
        ++row;
    }
    public boolean isLeftLimitExceed() {
        return (col < leftLimit);
    }
    public void decrementCol() {
        --col;
    }
    public void decrementDownLimit() {
        --downLimit;
    }
    public void decrementRightLimit() {
        --rightLimit;
    }
    public boolean isDownLimitExceed() {
        return (row > downLimit);
    }
    public boolean isRightLimitExceed() {
        return (col > rightLimit);
    }

    public void incrementUpLimit() {
        ++upLimit;
    }
}

public class MatrixTraverseClock extends MatrixTraverse {
    public MatrixTraverseClock() {
        super(TraverseDirection.RIGHT);
    }
    public void traverseUp() {
        decrementRow();
        if (isUpLimitExceed()) {
            incrementRow();
            incrementCol();
            incrementLeftLimit();
            moveRight();
        }
    }
    public void traverseLeft() {
        decrementCol();
        if (isLeftLimitExceed()) {
            incrementCol();
            decrementRow();
            decrementDownLimit();
            moveUp();
        }
    }
    public void traverseDown() {
        incrementRow();
        if (isDownLimitExceed()) {
            decrementRow();
            decrementCol();
            decrementRightLimit();
            moveLeft();
        }
    }
    public void traverseRight() {
        incrementCol();
        if (isRightLimitExceed()) {
            decrementCol();
            incrementRow();
            incrementUpLimit();
            moveDown();
        }
    }
}

public class MatrixTraverseCounterClock extends MatrixTraverse {
    public MatrixTraverseCounterClock() {
        super(TraverseDirection.DOWN);
    }
    public void traverseUp() {
        decrementRow();
        if (isUpLimitExceed()) {
            incrementRow();
            decrementCol();
            decrementRightLimit();
            moveLeft();
        }
    }
    public void traverseLeft() {
        decrementCol();
        if (isLeftLimitExceed()) {
            incrementCol();
            incrementRow();
            incrementUpLimit();
            moveDown();
        }
    }
    public void traverseDown() {
        incrementRow();
        if (isDownLimitExceed()) {
            decrementRow();
            incrementCol();
            incrementLeftLimit();
            moveRight();

        }
    }
    public void traverseRight() {
        incrementCol();
        if (isRightLimitExceed()) {
            decrementCol();
            decrementRow();
            decrementDownLimit();
            moveUp();
        }
    }
}


For Testing
final int[][] inputMatrix = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        final int[] expectedResult = {1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5};
        final MatrixTraverse matrixTraverse = new MatrixTraverseClock();

        Assert.assertArrayEquals(expectedResult,
                matrixTraverse.traverseMatrix(inputMatrix));


final int[] expectedResult1 = {1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 6, 3, 2, 5};
        final MatrixTraverse matrixTraverse = new MatrixTraverseCounterClock();

        Assert.assertArrayEquals(expectedResult1,
                matrixTraverse.traverseMatrix(inputMatrix));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few remarks about your **object-oriented design**:

- It's odd that the `matrixCount` and `up/down/left/rightLimit`s are part of the state of the object, but `matrix` itself isn't.
- I think `matrix` should be an instance variable along with all the others — in which case it should be passed into the constructor, not `traverseMatrix()`.
- Alternatively, *all* of the variables would be *local* variables in `traverseMatrix(int[][])`.  But that would be an excessively complex method.  I don't recommend this.
- Class names should be nouns; method names should be verbs.  I would rename `MatrixTraverse` and `traverseMatrix()` to `MatrixTraverser` and `traverse()`, respectively.
- You could consider this object an `Iterator`.  I've written it that way in the solution below.  Then you could have a convenience method called `traverse()` that repeatedly calls `next()` and assembles the whole array.

The main problem with your solution is lack of generality: up/down/left/right are each treated as special cases, so **all of your code appears in quadruplicate**.

You seem to have defined a `TraverseDirection` enum, which was not included in your post.  I'll assume that it's just a dumb enum of four elements.  You should make the enum more helpful.

We have an abstract base class, an enum, a clockwise iterator subclass, and an anticlockwise iterator subclass.  For code organization, I would make the latter three static inner classes within the first.  Inner classes would also save you from the repetitive naming (`MatrixTraverse`, `TraversalDirection`, `MatrixTraverseClock`, `MatrixTraverseCounterClock`).

An outline of the solution could be:

```
public abstract class MatrixTraverser implements Iterator<Integer> {
    protected static enum Direction {
        UP      (-1, 0),
        RIGHT   (0, +1),
        DOWN    (+1, 0),
        LEFT    (0, -1);

        public final int rowIncr, colIncr;

        /**
          * +1 if it represents "positive" movement; -1 if "negative" movement
          */
        public final int signum;

        private Direction(int rowIncr, int colIncr) {
            this.rowIncr = rowIncr;
            this.colIncr = colIncr;
            this.signum = this.rowIncr + this.colIncr;
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static class Clockwise extends MatrixTraverser {
        public Clockwise(int[][] matrix) {
            super(matrix, Direction.RIGHT);
        }

        @Override
        protected Direction nextDirection(Direction direction) {
            switch (direction) {
              case RIGHT: return Direction.DOWN;
              case DOWN:  return Direction.LEFT;
              case LEFT:  return Direction.UP;
              case UP:    return Direction.RIGHT;
            }
            assert false;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static class AntiClockwise extends MatrixTraverser {
        public AntiClockwise(int[][] matrix) {
            super(matrix, Direction.DOWN);
        }

        @Override
        protected Direction nextDirection(Direction direction) {
            switch (direction) {
              case DOWN:  return Direction.RIGHT;
              case RIGHT: return Direction.UP;
              case UP:    return Direction.LEFT;
              case LEFT:  return Direction.DOWN;
            }
            assert false;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public MatrixTraverser(int[][] matrix, Direction direction) {
        ...
    }

    public int[] traverse() {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Each subclass of `MatrixTraverser` does the minimum necessary to specialize the general solution.

Oh, and here's the test case.  Note that you can use it either as an iterator or call a convenience function to fetch the entire path at once.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] m = {{ 0,  1,  2,  3},
                 { 4,  5,  6,  7},
                 { 8,  9, 10, 11},
                 {12, 13, 14, 15}};

    MatrixTraverser t = new MatrixTraverser.Clockwise(m);
    while (t.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(t.next() + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    int[] spiral = new MatrixTraverser.AntiClockwise(m).traverse();
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(spiral));
}
```

At this point, you could try to fill in the blanks.  Or, read on to see what I came up with.

---

```
private final int[][] matrix;
private int row, col;
private int itemsRemaining;
private Direction direction;
private int[] limits = new int[Direction.values().length];

public MatrixTraverser(int[][] matrix, Direction direction) {
    this.matrix = matrix;
    this.direction = direction;
    this.itemsRemaining = matrix.length * matrix[0].length;

    this.limits[Direction.DOWN.ordinal()] = matrix.length - 1;
    this.limits[Direction.RIGHT.ordinal()] = matrix[0].length - 1;

    // Stay out of row 0 or col 0 on the next round of the spiral
    this.limits[this.prevDirection(direction).ordinal()] = 1;
}

@Override
public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    return this.itemsRemaining > 0;
}

@Override
public Integer next() {
    this.itemsRemaining--;
    int n = this.matrix[this.row][this.col];
    this.advance();
    return n;
}

private void advance() {
    int rowIncr = this.direction.rowIncr;
    int colIncr = this.direction.colIncr;
    this.row += rowIncr;
    this.col += colIncr;

    if ( (rowIncr < 0 && row == limits[Direction.UP.ordinal()]) ||
         (rowIncr > 0 && row == limits[Direction.DOWN.ordinal()]) ||
         (colIncr < 0 && col == limits[Direction.LEFT.ordinal()]) ||
         (colIncr > 0 && col == limits[Direction.RIGHT.ordinal()]) ) {
        this.limits[this.direction.ordinal()] -= this.direction.signum;
        this.direction = this.nextDirection(this.direction);
    }
}

protected abstract Direction nextDirection(Direction direction);

private Direction prevDirection(Direction direction) {
    for (Direction d : Direction.values()) {
        if (this.nextDirection(d) == direction) {
            return d;
        }
    }
    assert false;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

public int[] traverse() {
    int[] ret = new int[this.itemsRemaining];
    int i = 0;
    while (this.hasNext()) {
        ret[i++] = this.next();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable comments. I also updated sample.